# When OutOfMemoryException occurs?

Tags: c#, memory-management

Consider this code:

```
string value = new string('a', int.MaxValue);
```

When we run that code OutOfMemoryException occurs.[Physical memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(VS.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2003) limits in Windows 8 is 128 GB.

**So why .Net throw `OutOfMemoryException` for that code?**

Also this code never throw OutOfMemoryException :

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000000; i++)
{
    list.Add(new string('a', 100 ));
}
```

I run it on 64 bit mode.

Comment: *physical* memory is just about irrelevant when it comes to out of memory errors. You might want to read [It's the address space, stupid](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130628-00/?p=3963)

Comment: Strings cannot have more than 2^30 (1,073,741,824) characters, since a 2GB limit is imposed by the Microsoft CLR (Common Language Runtime).

Comment: Trivia: That for loop is broken, 100000000000 is greater than `int.MaxValue`, you need to use a long instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum size for an object in .NET is 2 GB, even with [`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) enabled on 64 bits systems (the documentation on `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` reads *The maximum size for strings and other non-array objects is unchanged.*, I guess because of the way it was implemented).

That means you can only allocate a string with a size of 2GB. Since `sizeof(char)` is 2 and you have a little overhead in the class itself, the maximum size you can set is `int.MaxValue / 2 - 32`.

Answer (score 4):

You need 1 int.MaxValue * 2 of **contiguous** memory for your first example. Your 2nd example needs 100000000000 100 byte * 2 of contiguous memory.

.NET just can't find a single chunk big enough to fit it all into one space.

There also is a 2GB hard limit on object sizes. On 64 bit platforms you can make it larger with [`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx) but that setting affects arrays only and will not affect the limit on strings.

Comment: .NET won't even search for that much space. There's a 2GB limit on object sizes, even under x64 (except for arrays if that option is enabled)

Comment: Actually first part of this answer (until 2GB hard limit) is irrelevant to the question, because author runs in 64bit mode, and there it should be not a problem to find continuous 4GB chunk.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you could enable large object in application Settings. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520956/i-hit-an-outofmemoryexception-with-liststring-is-this-the-limit-or-am-i-miss - then greater then 2GB objects should be possible - no?

Comment: @TripleEEE no, go read the documentation I linked to in my answer. it specifically says it does not work on strings.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for this advice - i just missed this remark - good to know - thank you :)

Comment: The part about the second example is incorrect. The list stores references to string instances, and a reference is 4 bytes on 32 bit and 8 bytes on 64 bit systems. So the sequential memory that list requires is `100000000000 * IntPtr.Size` bytes, not `100000000000 100 byte * 2`.